# Restrict user to input real number only in C++

Tags: c++

How can I restrict the user to input real numbers only in C++ program?

**Example:**

double number;
cin >> number;

and it won't accept the input like: '12add' , 'abcd' etc...

can someone guides me to that? using bool value.
Thanks!

Comment: A selection would be to force the user to not input that specific kind of character. The `getchar()` function present in `conio.h` is perfect for this purpose due to the fact that it does not print the character on the screen - just notifying the program. For further detail, check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot force the user to give correct input. But you can ask them to give another input if previous was invalid. There are different procedures to do so. One is the following:

1. Use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a line
2. Parse and understand the line
3. If line is invalid, give error to user and go to 1

This is alright and quite common. It uses dynamic memory though. Another option would be:

1. Use `cin >> value;` like you normally do
2. Check `cin.fail()` to see if input was correctly read (check for `cin.eof()` also)
3. If failed, ignore all input until whitespace:

   ```
   char c;
   while (cin >> c)
       if (isspace(c))
           break;
   ```

This has the added advantage that in an erroneous input like this:

```
abc 12.14
```

you don't ignore the whole line, but just the `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this code to request a specific type of input(Except strings and chars).
The idea is to request any numeric type and use stringstream to see if it can be stored as the requested type, if not it will keep prompting the user until he inputs the requested type.

```
template <typename T> // will not work with strings or chars
T forceInputType_T() {
 T name;
 bool check = false;
 string temp;
 while (check == false) {
    cin >> temp;
    stringstream stream(temp);
    if (stream >> number) {
        check = true;
    } else {
    cout << "Invalid input type, try again..." << endl;
    }
}
return name;
```

}

If you want to use a Boolean then you could check every character in the string if it contains a number than return false and keep asking for an valid input with a loop !

Comment: That screams for having `_int` replaced with `template<typename result_type>`. Anyhow, if you explained what it does and why, it could become a really good answer.

Comment: So true @UlrichEckhardt, let me fix that !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot avoid it... You can accept a string as input and parse the string (maybe with regex) for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your data as a `std::string` then use one of the standard string conversion function to see if the content matches your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict what user types on the keyboard. You can accept it as `std::string` and use `boost::lexical_cast` to convert it to your expected number type and catch and process `boost::bad_lexical_cast` exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
double number
if (cin >> number) {
    do_stuff_with(number);
} else {
    std::cerr << "That wasn't a number!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve it

```
double inputNumber()
{
    string str;
    regex regex_double("-?[0-9]+.?[0-9]+");
    do
    {
        cout << "Input a positive number: ";
        cin >> str;
    }while(!regex_match(str,regex_double));

    return stod(str);
}
```

Remember that include regex library in the header.

Comment: Seemingly, you do not show error messages regarding what format the user desires, which is not what the author wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Input a positive whole integer: ";
    string currentInput;
    while (true) {
        char ch = getch();
        if (ch <= '9' and ch >= '0') cout << ch; currentInput += ch;
        // Handle other keys (like backspace, etc)
        else if (ch == '\r') cout << endl; break;
    }
}
```